# Final image formation in these 2 cases:

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

Can someone please explain *simply* how we determine how many times we have to consider reflection and refraction to obtain final image.
Example a: [image]
Here they only considered refraction twice to obtain final image.

Example b:
[image]

But over here, they did refraction, reflection and refraction again for final image formation.

PS: This isn't a homework question.

Comment: It is unclear what is confusing you. In the first problem the light passes through two lenses, hence two refractions. In the second the light passes through a lens, is reflected from a mirror and then passes through the lens again, hence two refractions and a reflection.